# Select preenchido via ajax ao selecionar valor de outro select enviando null para php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cakephp

Tenho um select que preenche outro select via ajax, todos os valores são preenchidos corretamente, porém ao salvar, ele envia null.

*Primeiro select:*

```
<select name="clientesel" class="form-control js-example-basic-multiple" id="clientesel" >
    <option value="">Selecione</option>                         
    <?php foreach ($clientes as $cliente) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $cliente['Cliente']['cli_codigo_id']; ?>"><?php echo $cliente['Cliente']['cli_codigo_id'] . " - " . $cliente['Pessoas']['pes_razao_nome']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

*Segundo select*

```
<select name="pagamento" class="form-control" id="pagamento">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <?php foreach ($form_pagto as $pgto) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $pgto['FormaPagamento']['frec_codigo_id']; ?>"><?php echo $pgto['FormaPagamento']['frec_descricao']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

*JS que preenche o segundo a partir do primeiro*

```
$('#pagamento').val(data.Cliente.cli_forma_recebimento);
$("#pagamento option").each(function() {
    if($(this).val() == data.Cliente.cli_forma_recebimento) {
        $(this).attr("selected", true);
    }
});
```

*HTML após execução do ajax*

```
<select name="pagamento" class="form-control" id="pagamento" disabled="true">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option value="01" selected="selected">CHEQUE</option>
    <option value="02">BOLETO</option>
    <option value="03">DEPÓSITO</option>
    <option value="05">VALE</option>
    <option value="06">TRANSFERÊNCIA</option>
    <option value="07">SOMENTE DINHEIRO</option>
    <option value="08">SEM FATURA</option>
    <option value="09">CARTÃO DE DÉBITO</option>
    <option value="10">CARTÃO DE CRÉDITO</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Tente remover o `disabled`  antes de enviar os dados.

Comment: Substitui o disabled por readonly, resolveu! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Que bom, mas só para informação, `readonly` só funciona em `input` e `textarea`, então ainda vai ser possível alterar o valor do select. Se for importante o usuário não poder alterar o valor sugiro que faça como no exemplo, usando `bind` no `submit`, segue o [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1191365/3228982)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução foi remover o disabled antes de enviar os dados.